# AoCG2021 Day 18: Stripping Strips

Tags: code-golf, string, grid

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

The story continues from [AoC2018 Day 3](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/3).

*But you're not Bubbler, you're Lyxal! [yeah, I know.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59905194#59905194)*

---

After a long period of chaos, the Elves have finally agreed on how to cut the fabric. Unfortunately, the next day they have come up with how to utilize the leftovers - make a super long present wrapping strip. Well, if it can shrink Santa, it might be able to shrink presents as well...

The description of the strip is a string of `ODCF`, which happens to be the first letters of "up down left right" in Elvish (totally not [this Elvish](https://funtranslations.com/elvish)). Divide the fabric into a grid of 1cm × 1cm square cells, select a starting cell somewhere in the middle, and then move around according to the description to claim the strip.

So if the string is `OOCOFFFDD`, you would get this strip, starting at X:

```
OFFF
CO.D
.O.D
.X..
```

... Except that the strip the Elves gave to you is self-intersecting, so it simply doesn't work (a 1cm² fabric part doesn't magically become 2cm² - well, it's physics, at least until Santa comes).

Given the string `OOCOFFFDDCCCD`, the `?` is where the strip self-intersects:

```
OFFF
CO.D
C?CD
DX..
```

In order to avoid the `?` cell becoming a problem, you can take its substring (a contiguous part of the given string) in two ways: `OOCOFFFDDC` (cutting away the last 3 chars) and `COFFFDDCCCD` (cutting away the first 2 chars) gives, respectively,

```
OFFF
CO.D
.OCD
.X..

OFFF
CX.D
CCCD
D...
```

Among the two and all the other options, the latter of the two above is the longest possible.

Given a nonempty string of `ODCF`, determine the length of its longest substring out of which you can make a valid (non-self-intersecting) strip. Assume the fabric leftover is large enough to cover any valid substring of the input.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
C -> 1
ODD -> 2 (DD)
OOCOFFFDD -> 9 (whole input)
OOCOFFFDDCCCD -> 11 (whole input minus first 2)
OOOFFDCCCDFFFDCOOO -> 12 (minus first 3 and last 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

## TypeScript Types, 537 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type a<T,P=0,N=[1,0][P]>=T extends[N,...infer T]?T:[...T,P];type b<T>=T extends{[K in keyof T]:{[L in keyof T]:K extends L?0:T[K]extends T[L]?T:0}[number]}[number]?never:T;type c<T>=T extends[{},...infer U]?T|c<U>:T;type d<T>=T extends[...infer U,{}]?T|d<U>:T;type e<T,K=T extends T?keyof T:0>=T extends T?[K]extends[keyof T]?T:never:0;type f<S,A=[],P=[[],[]],B=[...A,P],X=P[0],Y=P[1]>=S extends`${infer C}${infer R}`?f<R,B,{O:[X,a<Y>],D:[X,a<Y,1>],F:[a<X>,Y],C:[a<X,1>,Y]}[C]>:B;type M<T>=a<e<b<c<d<f<T>>>>>,1,{}>["length"]
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAQwB4AVAGgAUBeABkoDlaBtARkvoF1XruAfLXKF0AD3DpEAE0ismlAHTLYiAGbpUhctwD85AFytliqvwDcuAoQBGFISPGSZkAN6sA0oVWEA1uhxkNW1uA3cAGW9EPwCgkIMvJylZQnDdegNyT24kl21WcL1DegBfVkQAVwBbG01uMsqaut1EdAA3TUzLfCIAY3thUQlkuVcSpRV1TUIAVSKAH36ZgS6rImkBx2GXY0mNLRnKMYWN5dWe0QpKD0HclPJdf0Dg4och53vdbLu5J7idfQGVodVAGejdaxqUgAZUoAEE2NwaGxWEjUUiAEJsExwmhIgAatGorB4lAAmkSOIJaND3iMAAYAElcqn2hAAwiVmazpgAlEr03RQ3mUDFHADyRnxlDIZIESIAIlKZaQyZR2PLKAAxIxkfECclI9m60jSjWGsrswQGDEQogAWQGZHQpDs-Q2UPIAm93vVRxKAlYACIADZSeDgAAWQe4mGwF3I9EItEIjqD7KDAkwIEIuYAerp49ZyOxk6nSEHxQqFZns8Bc4QC0WiOQAExltPi8Xs8VavvV2s5-OFtbaADMHYrXZ7fa11fZC5rWaHjZHCYALJPK13+wv2QrZwqe13B-Xh5ggA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

```
// Increment/decrement an integer stored as e.g. [0, 0] for 2, [1, 1, 1] for -3, and [] for 0
// Invoked as Inc<T> to increment, or Inc<T, 1> to decrement
type Inc<T, Pos = 0, Neg = [1, 0][Pos]> = T extends [Neg, ...infer T] ? T : [...T, Pos]

// Filters a union of tuples for those with no duplicate elements
type FilterNoDuplicates<T> =
  // Map over the union T
  T extends
    {
      // Map over the tuple T
      [K in keyof T]: {
        // Map over the tuple T
        [L in keyof T]:
          // If K != L and T[K] == T[L], return T
          K extends L ? 0 : T[K] extends T[L] ? T : 0
      }[number] 
    }[number]
      // If any returned T, omit T from the union
      ? never
      // Otherwise, keep T in the union
      : T

// Get all prefixes of T as a union (e.g. [1,2,3] -> [] | [1] | [1,2] | [1,2,3])
type Prefixes<T> = T extends [{}, ...infer U] ? T | Prefixes<U> : T

// Get all suffixes of T as a union (e.g. [1,2,3] -> [] | [3] | [2,3] | [1,2,3])
type Suffixes<T> = T extends [...infer U, {}] ? T | Suffixes<U> : T

// Filter a union of tuples, T, for those with the maximum length
type Longest<T, K = T extends T ? keyof T : 0> = T extends T ? [K] extends [keyof T] ? T : never : 0

// Convert a path like "ODCF" to its path (a list of pairs of integers, starting with (0,0))
type GetPath<
  Str,
  // The current path, not including the current position
  Path = [],
  // The current position
  Pos = [[],[]],
  // Aliases
  NewPath = [...Path, Pos],
  Pos0 = Pos[0],
  Pos1 = Pos[1]
> =
  // Get the first character of Str
  Str extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}`
    // Recurse
    ? GetPath<
      // Set Str to Rest
      Rest,
      // Set Path to NewPath
      NewPath,
      // Update Pos based on Char
      {
        O: [Pos0, Inc<Pos1>],
        D: [Pos0, Inc<Pos1, 1>],
        F: [Inc<Pos0>, Pos1],
        C: [Inc<Pos0,1>, Pos1]
      }[Char]
    >
    // Str is empty
    : NewPath

// Convert Str to a path, find all subpaths, filter the subpaths
// for no duplicates, find the longest, return its length minus 1
type Main<Str> = Inc<Longest<FilterNoDuplicates<Prefixes<Suffixes<GetPath<Str>>>>>,1,{}>["length"]
```

Comment: ah yes Typescript's typing system - the perfect language for AoCG ;p

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/) <strike>106</strike>, <strike>103</strike> (@pxeger), <strike>96</strike> (@ovs), <strike>89</strike>, 84 bytes

```python
lambda s,*i,x=0:max(len(i:=[x,*i[:[*i,x:=x+1j**"CDF".find(j)].index(x)]])for j in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYuxCoMwFEV3vyI4vWdFKl1KINMLWfMB1sGiwYjGoJamX5/GTp3uPedy/ecYV3e7@y0a8Yhztzz7ju1lYcsgrnzpAsyDA8tFE5JseHMuXIRLPRVFTlLllbGuhwnbKuUQIGDbolk3NjHr2I7xPdp5YDX3m3UHGLDOvw5AxKjTP9OSVEYpZKY1aaXUfyOikxL86uko4Rc)

##### Older versions

```python
lambda s,i=[0],x=0:max(len(i:=[x:=x+1j**"CDF".find(j)]+i[:(i+[x]).index(x)])for j in s)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoMgFEV3v4J04qk1mi4NCROGlQ@gDDZKfEaRqE3p11Ps1Omec4brP8e4utvdb9HyR5y75dl3ZC@R69qUgdds6QKdB0eRcR0YD0Uz5flFtPJSWXQ9ncAUqBnFQgcDVUpDoAEM2HUjE0FHdrg28T3iPJCG@Q3dQS1F518HBYCo0lemWiEzkabNlBJKSvlPQojTkvzwbCLpFw)

```python
lambda s,i=[0],x=0:max(len(i:=i[(x:=x+1j**"CDF".find(j))in i and-~i.index(x):]+[x])for j in s)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9CoMwFIV3nyJ0SvxD6VICma5kzQNYhxQNXtEY1NJ06aunsVOnc76Pw3HvY1zt9ea2YMQ9zHp59JrsOYq26nIvKr5oT@fBUuQCW@q58Fk9pekFGnkpDdqeToyhJUi07YsPllENnnrGu6z1HTPrRiYSBzsr6vAacR5Izd2G9qCGonXPgzLGgoqHiWpAJhCjSZQCJaX8bwBwUoRfPR1E/AI)

```python
x=m=0;i=[]
for j in input():
 i+=x,;x+=1j**"CDF".find(j)
 while x in i:_,*i=i
 m=max(m,len(i))
print(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETv@xUhp8RKqfSm7Gkl13xAKaW0EVdMFLE0/fo02kthYeYN7Mz8WfspnNO759GJqnbRPZSUMkX0eGoYL1fopkUMgkO@@bUqXYPgA8ayiQeshqKQ1Bp57Dg81aBB/Kri/lDfyoKRQXj096h8ObqgWGuYFw6r8jrlLZ1sbgDbkgHK0oK1ZI0x/46INsqw2y2jjF8)

```python
x=m=0;i=[]
for j in input():
 i+=[x];x+=1j**"CDF".find(j)
 while x in i:i.pop(0)
 m=max(m,len(i))
print(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETv@YqQ08YWUXpTclrJNR8gHkobccXEIJamX59GeykM7LyBmQ2ffVr9Lb0nWiyvGxvtA4QQKSqnqpZUP7Bx3fjMyWeF1w6yYZwuqo9DGy@qnotCYKdFOZJ/wiwZ/23Fs9FQGdYAVY6dcvcI7rpYDyQlCxv5HZxM@Z1MJm8w06FmmE/HjEGjtf53iHhQhtMeGWb8Ag)

Comment: `i+=[x]` -> `i+=x,`; `i.pop(0)` -> `_,*i=i`

Comment: `while x in i:_,*i=i` can be rewritten as `i=i[x in i and-~i.index(x):]`, which is longer, but with throwing a lot of Python 3.8 at it gets to [99 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY2xCoMwGIT3PEXIlF@rVLqUQKZfsuYBxEFqxF/aGMTSdOmrp7FTp7vvOO7Ce59Xf7mGLb1mujveKBfdTQohUjxp0t25Z2Ejv8vHEOXdeUlKUyej0rFslqIQ2BpRT@RHuQCQ58QHP1YfqnPkooyg@rKLPUzrxhd@FHx47hKgaiDlH0g2TzDbomGYpWXWojXG/DtEPCjDzx4ZZvwC) (And 96 as a *lambda* function)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
ＦＬθ«Ｆ✂θιＦ¬℅ＫＫ✳⊗⌕FOCκ¹ψ⊞υＬＫＡ⎚»Ｉ⌈υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BDsIgEEXX7SlIV0NSF65dGQgrlSaeAClaUgopBaMxnh2hdTbz58@bP3IQXjphUro7j@Ck7CMMMGOMPnW1WlejpYK5RTqbq3NxAbjvtRUGOqVGwLlQ57UNQLVXMmhngbp4M6oHpm0PDeOkadGYwRbt8aGuNvy9yrgMEFv0f14ij8aU1LwkRgkPWX3r7YSIJcBZvPQUJ4gFSolzzhglhFBWeh7T7ml@) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＬθ«
```

Loop over each suffix.

```
Ｆ✂θι
```

Loop over the characters in the suffix.

```
Ｆ¬℅ＫＫ
```

Stop if the strip self-intersects.

```
✳⊗⌕FOCκ¹
```

Mark the current cell as part of the strip and move to where the next cell should be.

```
ψ
```

Ensure that the final cell is not part of the strip. This will remove the wrong cell if the strip self-intersected but only the count matters.

```
⊞υＬＫＡ
```

Record the number of cells marked as part of the strip.

```
⎚
```

Clear the canvas ready for the next suffix or to output the result.

```
»Ｉ⌈υ
```

Output the maximum possible strip length found.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>40</s> 35 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
⌈´·{⊑/¬«∊+`<˘»⍉¬4|31‿37|⌜9×@-∾@}¨↓
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oyIwrTCt3viipEvwqzCq+KIiitgPMuYwrvijYnCrDR8MzHigL8zN3zijJw5w5dALfCdlaniiL5AfcKo4oaTCgoKPuKLiOKfnEbCqCDin6giQyIKIk9ERCIKIk9PQ09GRkZERCIKIk9PQ09GRkZERENDQ0QiCiJPT09GRkRDQ0NERkZGRENPT08i4p+p)

BQN doesn't support complex numbers yet, which means the directions have to be encoded as tuples by `<˘⍉¬4|31‿37|⌜9×@-`:

```
⟨ 'O' ⟨ ¯1 0 ⟩ ⟩ ⟨ 'D' ⟨ 1 0 ⟩ ⟩ ⟨ 'C' ⟨ 0 ¯1 ⟩ ⟩ ⟨ 'F' ⟨ 0 1 ⟩ ⟩
```

We iterate over the suffixes `↓`, and get the length of the longest unique prefix of each. The maximum of that is the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 98 bytes

```
s->vecmax([vecmin([#[1|k<-[j..p=#s+a=0],p*=a+=I^(Vecsmall(s)[k]%69)]+j-i|j<-[i..#s]])|i<-[1..#s]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc09C4MwEAbgvxIihaSaUJdCoXGJCJ3cuoQUgmiJXxymlBb87/YUp07vPS/cHbjJiycsDVFLENm7rgb3YWZNPzITmXTursK0UoKKQuzUySZwVC5Wtwe711UYXN@zwE1nD@cLt3Er/NzihpcyCtby2SPSHYsD6L8sEJERmPz4wpGuoKTBIzwhhmqaEFrm@RalLoui@IPWei/Qm9ZaIym@@AE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 99 bytes

```
f=lambda a,B=1,c=0,*v:a>""and max(B*f(a[1:]),~f(a[1:],0,r:=c+1j**'OCD'.find(a[0]),*v,c)*~-(r in v))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3k9NscxJzk1ISFRJ1nGwNdZJtDXS0yqwS7ZSUEvNSFHITKzSctNI0EqMNrWI1deqgLB0DnSIr22RtwywtLXV_Zxd1vbTMvBSgnAFQkVaZTrKmVp2uRpFCZp5CmaYm1KqcgqLMvBKNNA11Z3VNTS44z9_FBZXv7-zv5uaGS9TZ2RldBigBFgbJOwO56jA7Yd4EAA)

Tricks:

- `a>""` is the same as `bool(a)`, since strings are compared lexicographically, and can be used as a recursive base-case because it returns `0` when `a` is empty, unlike simply `a and`
- `a>""` is a sufficient base-case to prevent infinite recursion, which allows shorter conditionals later on because they're allowed to be strictly evaluated (mostly using `*`, and the fact that the output is always positive so we can happily pass `0` to `max`)
- `~X*~-Y` = `-~X*-~-Y` = `(1+X)*(1-Y)` = `(1+X)*(not Y)`
- With the help of the flag variable `B`, I combine the loops searching for the shortest substring into one recursive function

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 150 bytes

```rust
|i:&str|i.bytes().scan((vec![],[0,0]),|(v,p),c|{v.push(*p);p[c as usize%23&1]+=1-c as i64%2*2;while v.contains(&p){v.remove(0);};Some(v.len())}).max()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRS8MwFIXf@yvuBis3M4a1iqBlTx177YOPpUgsKQusaUzSTl3722taJ0zxvOV8h5PDNa11Y6Wg5lIhgXMAXkfhoIItjL18Cq0zvWSvH05YJMyWXCF2olzkBc03dFMQ2mNHNaFlf@6Ybu0B15okOi@BW2it/BSr@C6MipttdDt78uF@Fa/j5HSQRwEdKxvl/PcWQ018hRF10wnckGRInptaYMeOwo8jA2E1f0cyThuTYJ5aNQZQKt06ClzZkzAEpIIwn@kkXKZLChGhV06223kv/u1labbf72fy@D9J03Si0Z@yzNOZTaHUP6fMT3lxuekkbq0w7kW8LbD6Hk1Yq06GayQU1pf9yZwfgiEYvwA)

Ungolfed:

```rust
|i: &str| {
    i.bytes()
        .scan((vec![], [0, 0]), |(v, p), c| {
            v.push(*p);
            p[c as usize % 23 & 1] += 1 - c as i64 % 2 * 2;
            while v.contains(&p) {
                v.remove(0);
            }
            Some(v.len())
        })
        .max()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 89 bytes

```
Max[s=Subsequences;Length/@Select[s[I^ToCharacterCode@#~Mod~69],FreeQ[Tr/@Rest@s@#,0]&]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XchBC4IwGIDhvzImeDLsFEQYg08GQWKlt7Fgzc8UUmmbEET@9WXRqdPL83bKNdgp12rla5L4TD2ETYrxYvE@Yq/RbvbYX10TswJvqJ2wYncuB2iUUdqhgaFCFkzZUE2rtYy4QTyK0sTshNYxy4JoKUMpQ38wbe9EQBZbUotAShKSmJEnBRoRmqfpNznknPM/AMBvzP7qs2Emffk3)

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 195 bytes:

```
f=lambda d,x,y:{'O':(x+1,y),'C':(x,y-1),'D':(x-1,y),'F':(x,y+1)}[d]
g=lambda s,p=(0,0),q=[]:0 if not s or(n:=f(s[0],*p))in q else g(s[1:],n,q+[p])+1
r=lambda x:max(g(x[i:])for i in range(len(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NaoQwFIX3PsXdeW@9A4ZuSsBVxK0PELKw@FPBiTG6iAzz7E7sMIUWujvn@7iH6/bta7bvH84fR19MzfWzbaDlwLu8pXUqMWSCd@JUnZn3i4i5PPPlyasnzwTddWuS4bWxsisw55x4KbSROYw92HmDFWaPVhY9rjo3/OaIRgsLdNPawRChkIYtL5l2hjKR@NdgkNcm4IBBj9JQP3sYIV76xg4dTp3FQESH86Pd0GP8lyj5aXVZ/u61qquq@o8qpf6aKL7x6VWsUR8P)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 108 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>Math.max(a&&f(a.slice(1)),Buffer(a).some(g=c=>g[g[[x,y]]=[x+=(c=c%13%5-2)%2,y+=~c%2]]||!++t,t=x=y=0),t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY49b4MwEED3/go3EpEtHFIcdehwGWrEVvEDEIPl2IQKcIRNC1LUv07tLm3zcdOd9N7TvYsPYeXQnNymNwe1LBoE7N@EOyadmLBYrzUWiW0bqXBKCH0dtVYDFiSxplO4Bgn7uqzLcqJzVUE5xYAlyCjdRc8bRiJG5xi@ZMSq6nx@jGNHHUwwwxOhjizS9Na0KmlNjTVe8RUh6Gq2W5Q@XJBFlt1gPckQzjJyhRe8yPP8QvL4C8KfRw@ipj@N7r7HOf91w0PpPxF1TT9apJvBOsRuZHzlpxFi3J@hFTL@3b/qDon@gFoRVrJ8Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```ruby
->s{*l=z=0;s.chars.map{|c|l<<z+=1i**"OCDF".index(c);_,*l=l while l!=l|l;l.size}.max-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664WivHtsrWwLpYLzkjsahYLzexoLomuSbHxqZK29YwU0tLyd/ZxU1JLzMvJbVCI1nTOl4HqCNHoTwjMydVIUfRNqcmxzpHrzizKrUWqLlC17D2f4FCWrSSs1IsF5jh7@ICZ/o7@7u5uWERcHZ2RhIEioFFQFLOQK5S7H8uAA)